# Routing from Django to Angular route

Tags: python, angularjs, django, routes, angular-ui-router

I have a Django backend and an Angular frontend.
I am using a package called django-invitations. When a user receives an invitation in an email they click on it and are taken to the app. django-invitations requires this line in settings.py

```
INVITATIONS_SIGNUP_REDIRECT = 'register'
```

This is the name of a route and reverse match is used to determine where to go.
The problem is I want the user to be taken to my sign-up page which is

http://example.com/#/registration

This is an Angular route. 
My urls.py contains this line

```
url(r'^register', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='register'),
```

This however takes the user to my index page and the url becomes

http://example.com/registration#/

How do I route a request from my Django backend to an Angular route with hash notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

Changed the line in urls.py to

```
url(r'^register/', views.redirect_to_register, name='register'),
```

Added a views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def redirect_to_register(request):
    return redirect('/#/register')
```

And it works.